# How to exit a blocking accept() call in Windows?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock

I have a blocking `accept()` call in a thread that is waiting for connection requests. When the application is about to close, I want to signal the thread that is waiting on `accept()` to exit gracefully. I have found in the documentation for Winsock that I can set a timeout value for `send()` and `recv()`, but I can't do that for `accept()`.

I have read that I can make the socket non-blocking and use `select()`, and pass a timeout value for `select()`, but I am looking for a solution for blocking sockets.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot ... at least not on "older" (pre-vista?) windows.

Comment: You don't need to switch to non-blocking to use `select()`, it can be used with blocking sockets, too. Call `select()` with timeout, and don't call `accept()` unless `select()` tells you a connection is waiting to be accepted. Otherwise yes, switch to non-blocking. You can use `WSAEventSelect()` with `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` to wait for socket events and a termination event at the same time. Or use an I/O Completion Port for socket events and post a termination event when needed.

Comment: CancelSynchronousIo() might also be a quick and easy fix.

Comment: Closing the socket always does a good job of jerking the floor mat.

Answer (score 5):

> I have read that I can make the socket non-blocking and use select(), and pass a timeout value for `select()`, but I am looking for a solution for blocking sockets.

You can do this on blocking socket:

```
sock = socket(...);
bind(sock, ...);
listen(sock, ...);

while (program_running()) 
{
    timeval timeout = {1, 0};
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(sock, &fds);

    select(sock+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &fds))
    {
        client = accept(sock, ...);

        // do things with client
    }
```

From [MSDN accept function documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx):

> The parameter readfds identifies the sockets that are to be checked for readability. If the socket is currently in the listen state, it will be marked as readable if an incoming connection request has been received such that an **accept is guaranteed to complete without blocking**.